# Bitbucket Rest APIs 2.0 for Enterprise

Tags: api, bitbucket, enterprise

I have used bitbucket's 1.0 APIs within our corporate version like this:

```
https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/repos
```

The 2.0 APIs say they are switching to the URLs that look like this:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/...
```

But when I try to use that style, it no longer works to get any information from within my organization. Similarly it doesn't recognize my userID as a valid userID, likely because my userID only makes sense from within my organization. I've looked for documentation on what the URLs look like for enterprise users and I've tried so many different varieties to try to get the 2.0 URLs to work but to no avail. They say 1.0 is already depreciated and will likely be disabled mid-2019, but as of now I see no documentation on how enterprise users can connect to the 2.0 APIs. Anyone had any experience with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about two separate APIs - the first is for Bitbucket Server (the on-premise version), but api.bitbucket.org is for Bitbucket Cloud (the version hosted by Atlassian). The difference here is the `/rest/` at the beginning, which is not present in the api.bitbucket.org URL structure (for 1.0 or 2.0).

The Bitbucket Server API is tied to the Bitbucket Server version. If you are using Bitbucket Server, then your API isn't changing until somebody upgrades (or downgrades) your instance.